# NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count: ERROR while searching NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, search, nsmutablearray

I have the following situation where
I have an `NSMutableArray` filled with an `xml` file which I want to search.
When I enter something in the search field I get this Error:

```
-[NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b388b0
```

What does it means and how can I fix it??

I suppose the error is somewhere around here.

```
- (void)searchTableView{

 searchedList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 NSLog(@"new list %@", searchedList);
 NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
 NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for (NSDictionary *dictionary in list) {
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"TITLE"];
   [searchArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
 }

 for (NSString *TempArray in searchArray) {
  NSRange titleResults = [TempArray rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
  if (titleResults.length > 0) 
  [searchedList addObject:TempArray];
 }
 [searchArray release];
 searchArray = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

it means you are calling a method designed for an NSArray (`countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count` on a NSString.

I don't know ifthis code is copy/paste from yours, but if so, at the end where you use `[searchList addObject:TempArray]` you don't have an object named `searchList`.

Also, work on your naming conventions. big time.

Comment: now that I changed my NSArray --> NSString and addObjectsFromArray --> addObject the Search filter works perfectly but when I empty the search field it craches again with "NSCFString count"

Comment: Did you get this up and running? I am stuck with mine as well. :\ please advice. Thank you!

Comment: Try rebuild (Clean + Build). Seriously.

Comment: For future users: On debugging deeper I found if you accidentally initialise a `NSArray *array = [dictionary valueForKey@"xyz"]` and the object for `xyz` does not exists or it is a `string = @""` then we end up with this error.

Comment: `if (![_array isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        _array = [NSArray array];
    }` use `NSMutableArray` according to need. as a sure solution that if you don't get an array object then make it a array object.

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat that was the answer for me.