# -[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I am unable to track down the cause of an IOS crash that keeps popping up. It only happens on the rare occasion to a very small subset of users. I can't follow the crash report back to anything in the app, therefore I didn't post any code. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?
Here is the thread reported by crashlytics as being the source of the crash...

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018663c2d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000197c480e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001866433a4 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186640154 ___forwarding___ + 928
4  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186542ccc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5  UIKit                          0x000000018b2d4400 +[_UIDynamicAnimation _updateAnimations:timer:] + 884
6  QuartzCore                     0x000000018aa1229c CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 32
7  QuartzCore                     0x000000018aa12134 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 324
8  IOKit                          0x00000001877ed470 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 376
9  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001865dedc4 __CFMachPortPerform + 180
10 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001865f3a54 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
11 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001865f39b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
12 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001865f1934 __CFRunLoopRun + 1640
13 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018651d2d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
14 GraphicsServices               0x000000018fbf36fc GSEventRunModal + 168
15 UIKit                          0x000000018b0e2fac UIApplicationMain + 1488
16 MyAppName                      0x00000001000c8394 main (main.m:7)
17 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001982c6a08 start + 4
```

The rest of the threads don't give me a lot more info either.

Comment: It has something to do with animations.  Do you do much animation in your app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count: ERROR while searching NSMuttableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659958/nscfstring-countbyenumeratingwithstateobjectscount-error-while-searching-nsmu)

Comment: Not much animation going on here.

Answer (score 2):

`-countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` is the method used to enumerate a collection in the for...in statement.

You are trying to enumerate an NSString (__NSCFString is one of the representations of it)  or a dangling pointer (whose class can be mistakenly reported as __NSCFstring) somewhere, instead of a collection.

Comment: This is a good point, but if I'm trying to enumerate an NSString somewhere, why is the crash report not pointing to something in the code base?

Comment: _Someone_ is calling a method on an NSString that isn't an NSString method. _You_ stored an NSString somewhere where you shouldn't.

Comment: Any pointers on the best way to track this down without being able to reproduce it myself?